# Shadow larger than the background image

Tags: html, css, background-image, shadow

Ran into this problem when I was trying to add shadows to the thumbnail border image. Is there any way around this? :s

[image]

Here's the chunk of the code:

```
#content .item{
 width: 285px;
 height: 240px;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
 padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
 background: url(../images/thumbnail.png) no-repeat;
 background-size: 285px 240px;
 box-shadow: -5px -5px 10px #CCC;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ju3hxjuu/4

Comment: i guess the shadow is on a container wrapping the thumbnail

Comment: jsfiddle.net/ju3hxjuu/4 @Harsh Yeah that's the problem :/

Comment: hey how about this http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/ju3hxjuu/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/ju3hxjuu/5/

u dont actually require an image to create thumbnail background

Html

```
<div class="item">    
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/t2cfwup.png" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Css:

```
body{
    background-color: #EEE;
}
.item{
     width: 285px;
     height: 240px;
     float: left;
     margin: 10px;
     padding: 15px;
     background-color:white; 
     background-size: 285px 240px;
     box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #CCC;
}
.item img{
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What is your problem Please Clearly Specify.

If you are talking about the white border around your images + shadow.
Then please note that the adding you just used making that white border because your div is larger than that of image inside that. If you want that shadow appear only around your images then you have to remove padding. like this :

```
#content .item{
 width: 285px;
 height: 240px;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
 background: url(../images/thumbnail.png) no-repeat;
 background-size: 285px 240px;
 box-shadow: -5px -5px 10px #CCC;
}
```

Comment: if this doesn't solves your problem then please paste HTML and clearly specify what you want.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ju3hxjuu/4/

@AZT Yes, that's what I was trying to do but by removing the padding the shadow does go where I want it to but then the image above it is no longer centred on the white thumbnail.